# Calculate $P(\{X \leq 1\} \smallsetminus \{Z=1\})$ for independent $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a random variable with $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1)$
>
> Let $Z$ be a random variable, independent of $X$ and defined by:
>
> $P(Z=-1)=P(Z=1)=1/2$
>
> Calculate $P(\{X \leq 1\} \smallsetminus \{Z=1\})$

My idea is to use the formula.

$P(A-B) = P(A)-P(A \cap B)$

Since $X$ and $Z$ are independent we can rewrite the formula:
$P(A-B) = P(A)-(P(A)·P(B))$

Firstly we calculate $P(A)=P(\{X\leq 1\})$

Since $X\sim e(1)$ we solve the integral:

$$P(A)=P(\{X\leq 1\}))=\int_0^1(1·e^{-1·x}) \, dx=1-e^{-1}$$

$$P(B)= \frac 1 2$$

$$P(A-B) = P(A)-P(A \cap B)= (1-e^{-1})-((1-e^{-1})·1/2)=\frac{1-e^{-1}}{2}$$

The above is correct im pretty sure. However my question is:

My first thought when I had to calculate this was that since $X$ and $Z$ are independent, it would be okay to ignore the subtraction of $Z$ and just solve for $X$, since $Z$ shouldn't affect it. Can anyone give a simple and intuitive explanation to why this isn't so? I can derive from the formulas that I should calculate it as I have done, but it's not 100% intuitive to me.

Comment: Unsure of your notation: If $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then $P(X \le 1\,|\,Z = 1) = P(X \le 1)$ because events $\{X\le1\}$ and $\{ Z=1\}$ are independent. The first has probability 0.6321206 and the second probability 1/2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. \ is subtracted in our books. So it says $P(X\leq 1 - Z=1)$

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification. Your answer seems OK.

Comment: See my edits for good MathJax usage. In particular, in the expression $$ P(\{X \leq 1\} \smallsetminus \{Z=1\}) $$ you shouldn't keep alternating in and out of MathJax. Just stay in MathJax from beginning to end. Similarly in  this: $$ X \sim e(1) $$

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to improve the coding for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it's more intuitive to think in terms of an intersection rather than a set difference. Note that $A-B = A \cap B^c$. Since $X$ and $Z$ are independent, so are the events $A \equiv \{X\leq 1\}$ and $B^c \equiv \{Z = -1\}$. Hence,
$$P(A - B) = P(A\cap B^c) = P(A)P(B^c) = (1 - e^{-1}) \times 1/2$$
So your question of why it's not ok to ignore the subtraction of $B$ from $A$ is equivalent to asking why it's not ok to ignore the multiplication of $1 - e^{-1}$ by $1/2$. I think this should be clear, given that we are calculating the probability of an intersection.

Comment: Ah, of course. Really helpful explanation. Thank you